# Entity Framework 6 add List of Child Objects

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a Country object that has a List of Territories as one of the properties. Here are the objects:

```
    [Table("COUNTRY")]
    public class Country : ICountry
    {
        [Column("COUNTRY_CD")]
        public int? Id { get; set; }

        [Column("COUNTRY_NAME")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<Territory> Territories { get; set; }

        List<ITerritory> ICountry.Territories
        {
            get
            {
                List<ITerritory> list = new List<ITerritory>();

                foreach (var item in Territories)
                {
                    list.Add(item);
                }

                return list;
            }

            set
            {
                Territories = new List<Territory>();

                foreach (var item in value)
                {
                    Territories.Add(item as Territory);
                }
            }
        }

    public class Territory : ITerritory
    {
        [Column("TERRITORY_CD")]
        public int? Id { get; set; }

        [Column("TERRITORY_NAME")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Column("COUNTRY_CD")]
        public int? CountryCode { get; set; } 
}
```

Note, I have:

> `List<ITerritory> ICountry.Territories`

So that I can keep just interface references inside other interfaces, but have a concrete List of Territory for Entity Framework.

My Country Repository looks like this:

```
public class CountryDbRepository : ICountryDbRepository
{
    private IUnityContainer _container;

    public CountryDbRepository()
    {
        IUnityContainer container = UnityCommon.GetContainer();
        _container = container;
    }

    public List<ICountry> GetAll()
    {
        IQueryable<Country> query;
        List<ICountry> list = new List<ICountry>();

        using (var db = new MainContext())
        {
            query = db.Countries;

            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                list.Add(item);
            }
        }

        return list;
    }

    public ICountry GetById(int id)
    {
        ICountry country = null;

        using (var db = new MainContext())
        {
            country = db.Countries.Where(s => s.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        return country;
    }      
}
```

Can I setup Entity Framework to populate the list of Territories? Or do I need to need a helper method that is called to populate that list?

Comment: From what I see, you already set up EF to populate `Territories`. By the way, you can use `Cast()`, like return `db.Countries.Cast<ICountry>().ToList()`.

Comment: The Territories list is null.

Comment: Well, of course you have to initialize `public List<Territory> Territories` in the constructor. Note that you also should add items to *that* (concrete) collection, not to the interfaced collection.